# does splitting querset requires cleaned data?

Tags: python, django, split, django-queryset

I have a queryset named fp_items and look like 201;202;205 etc...

Here how it looks like:

```
<QuerySet [{'fp_items': '201;203;204'}]>
```

I am trying to split these items into list because I would do another queryset to recall these items one by one.
Should I use cleaned data ? Why I can't split queryset output ?

I am getting this error:

> Exception Type:   AttributeError Exception Value:'QuerySet' object has
>   no attribute 'split'

```
fp_items = SWTypes.objects.filter(pk__in=id,swtype__in=swtype).values('fp_items')
fp = fp_items.split(';')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the output is q queryset not string to split.

you can iterate over all items and split them into a list

```
fp_items = SWTypes.objects.filter(pk__in=id,swtype__in=swtype).values_list('fp_items', flat=True)
res = []
for item in fp_items:
    res += item.split(";")
```

and use res as merged list of all splited content into a list